# How to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question which requires improvement:
[How did Superman know that Lois was falling to catch her in time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92059/super-hearing-or-super-what)

It is asking for an explanation of how Superman can apparently hear Lois but not his mother. I did not want an answer inconsistent with other events in the movie, Hence I also added two related questions.

The question is closed, hence here I am, asking how to improve this question.

Comment: Try to stick to one basic question...**the first one**. If you have other questions somewhat related then ask **separate** questions **based on the responses to the first one.** - Don't try to jam them all into a single question.

Comment: @Paulie_D , Done, asking only one question now.

Comment: Its been re-opened